# php script to update mysql table on click of link

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm new to php and need help.

My link as below:

```
//create a path to download
echo '<a download="Final_File_'.$filenames.'" name="save" href="'.$DownDir. "/".$filenames.'" target="_blank"><img src="images/Save File.png"/></a>';
//Query
$Query = 'UPDATE `tbl_download_log` SET `User_Id` = `User_Id`, `path` = `$DownDir. "/".$filenames`';
```

Saves a file on the click of the ImageLink and need to update the a table in MySQL DB named `tbl_download_log` with the 'user ID' & 'Download link' at the same time.

I established the connection and got the user ID as well.
Please help me to update both the thing in db table.

---

Updating new script in it.

```
<?php
$DownDir = "http://localhost/SGA-INTRANET/".$kmsroot. "/". $user. "/". $bu. "/". $client. "/". $project."/Final";
$filenames = "file.xlsx";

$pathDown1 = $DownDir. "/".$filenames;//download path

//using download functionality of HTML 5
echo '<a download="Final_File_'.$filenames.'" name="save" href="'.$pathDown1.'?id='.$name.'&filepath='.$pathDown1.'" target="_blank"><img src="images/Save File.png" title="Download the file"/></a>';
?>

<?php 

$ide = $_GET['id'];//EmployeeID
$file = $_GET['filepath'];// Path

if(isset($ide) && isset($file)) 
{
if(file_exists($file)) 
{
//save log to DB table 'tbl_km_file_download'
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "USERNAME", "PASSWORD", "DBNAME");
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `tbl_km_file_download` (`name`, `filename`) VALUES ('$ide', '$file')");
}
}

?>
```

which is downloading files but not updating the DB table. 
Please see the images.
[image: Case 1]
[image: Case 2]

Please help.

Comment: Do you use PDO or MySQLi for connecting to your database ?

Comment: onclick of the link you need to make an ajax call and send the necessary data as params in ajax and then on the php page you can insert data into the table

Comment: Or you do it with query strings

Comment: Please add your query also

Comment: How do I pass the data, through the href?

Comment: Is the SQL Query still in the same .php file as the link?

Comment: yes the sql query will be executed from the same `.php` page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass data through the href with **query strings**.

### Example

```
echo '<a href="path/download.php?id='.$user_id.'&file='.$file.'">CLICK THE LINK</a>';
```

**$file** should be a root-relative path, starting with a `/`.

Then in **download.php**:

```
<?php
$id   = $_GET['id'];
$file = $_GET['file'];

if(isset($id) && isset($file)) {
   if(file_exists($file)) {
      //connect to database .... (I show it with PDO)
      $db   = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DATABASENAME;charset=utf8', USERNAME, PASSWORD);
      $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `tbl_download_log` (`User_Id`, `path`) VALUES (?, ?)");
      $stmt->execute(array($id, $file));

      //download the file....       
      header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
      header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
      header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
      header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
      header('Expires: 0');
      header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
      header('Pragma: public');
      header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
      ob_clean();
      flush();
      readfile($file);
   } else echo "The file does not exist.";
} else echo "An error occurred.";
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, is `<a href="path/download.php?` will download the file and update the DB table at the same time?

Comment: I changed the code a little bit, if it doesnt work, make sure you have the current version